# How do I Send SMS to Active Directory Users

Tags: c#, active-directory, sms

How do I send an SMS to Active Directory Users. I want to design a small application (in C#) for my telecom operator client that will send various SMS based notifications to their (AD) users by using their SMS gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that the mobile number is stored in AD & you wish to pull this number out with a query and use the API provided by your SMS gateway to send a message?
You may want to look at [this code sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/QueryADwithDotNet.aspx).   You can query AD with `System.DirectoryServices.` Finding the mobile phone number attribute in the AD schema may be a little easier with [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx)
Hope this helps.